# How to change title color of menu's enclosing item in NavigationView's xml files

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a ***menu*** which is shown in a `NavigationView` (Side navigation).

The ***menu*** has this structure in which ***menu*** tags not only have their own children **item** tags, but they(the ***menu*** tags) are also enclosed within parent **item** tags.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item android:title="User Profile">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_user"
                android:title="Profile" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/account"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_secure"
                android:title="Account" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="Ride Now">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/find_ride"
                android:icon="@drawable/car_1"
                android:title="Find A Ride" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/offer_ride"
                android:icon="@drawable/car_1"
                android:title="Offer A Ride" />
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="Booking History">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/offered_rides"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Rides offered"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/booked_rides"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Rides Booked" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/cancelled_rides"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Rides Cancelled" />

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

I have been able to set the **item** title colors within the ***menu*** tags using:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_dark_green_scheme"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/app_white_scheme"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/app_white_scheme"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

but I need to set the title colors for **items** that are parents of the ***menu*** tags. How do I accomplish this?

Note: `@+id/nav_view` is the `NavigationView` that owns the **menu**

Please, I would prefer the answer to be xml based, instead of Java based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add android:textColorSecondary into your style.xml

paste the following code into the style you are using as the theme. You can change the color as you like.

```
 <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

it works for me

Comment: You said "it works for me"... Well I better tell you it sure works for me too. Thanks, @JDevoloper.

Comment: Yeah thats better :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to change the color of all items you have to do it by code:

```
public SpannableString getColoredSpannableString(String s, int color) {
    SpannableString str = new SpannableString(s);
    str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return str;
}

public void makeMenuItemColored(MenuItem mi, int color) {
    mi.setTitle(getColoredSpannableString(mi.getTitle().toString(), color));
}
```

and use it like this:

`makeMenuItemColored(mi, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));`

or  `makeMenuItemColored(mi, yourColor);`  
where `mi` is your menu item and you can choose a color resource or a color by `int`

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned that I would prefer the answer to be xml-based.

Comment: I don't think there is an xml attribute for a specific menu item

Comment: Please see the accepted answer.
Its all about controlling the properties of different item levels and the specified property controls it for outer item tags.

Comment: Doesn't this apply to all menu items?

Comment: No only to the top level items. I used app:itemTextColor="@color/app_white_scheme" to change the color for the items within the menu.(I placed this in the NavigationView's xml tag)